# Django: Passing arguments to ModelField at runtime

Tags: django, django-models

I am fairly new to Python + Django and I am stuck with the following problem. I have created a custom ModelField like:

```
class MyField(models.TextField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        # custom operations here
        # need access to variable xyz
```

The model using this field looks something like:

```
 class MyModel(models.Model):
     my_field = MyField()

     def __init__(self, model, xyz, *args, **kwargs):
         self.instance = model
         # how to pass xyz to ModelField before pre_save gets called?
         self.xyz = xyz 

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if self.instance:
             self.my_field = self.instance
```

Q: Like it says in the comment, is there a way to pass a variable to the ModelField instance at runtime, ideally before my_field.pre_save() gets called?

Comment: why don't you pass it in __init__ of MyModel?

Comment: When, exactly, do you want that to be called? "Before pre_save" isn't really descriptive enough.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: that's exactly what I am doing. xyz gets passed into MyModel's init() and from here I would like to pass it on so that I can use it in the ModelField's pre_save() method. Any ideas?

Comment: @IanClelland: Sorry, I should have explained it better. xyz is needed inside pre_save() (see the comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to pass the `xyz` variable on -- it is an instance variable on the model, so it is already present in the `model_instance` variable that gets passed to `pre_save()`

```
class MyField(models.TextField):

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        ...
        # Access model_instance.xyz here
        ...
        # Call the superclass in case it has work to do
        return super(MyField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)
```